# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Task Process

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that has a task process in it. In this process it is looking for a response from four different users.

Lets say three of these users approve the document, but the fourth user is out on long term sick and is unable to respond to their task. It could be months before they are back in the office.

How do I move the workflow along? I don't want to cancel it, and restart it again. Is there a way to set up the workflow so that it has a parallel surrogate approver? i.e. The workflow will stop and wait for the four people to respond OR wait for one particular user (an admin lets say) to respond, and it will resume the workflow.

So if the above scenario happens, the admin can approve their task and it will move the workflow along.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that currently with an admin. You can go to the workflow, and it will list out the tasks that are assigned. As an admin you can click on it and either reassign it, or approve/reject it.

- Goto the workflow status page of the item in question
- Click on the task that is "in waiting"
- Approve/Reject, or "Reassign", if that is an option

Comment: Excellent, thank you. One of those "can't see the forest for the trees" moments. Cheers!

Comment: no problem! We've all had those moments, thankfully not in front of a client!